# How to handle Auto Suggestion feild in app:Urgent

Tags: selenium, appium

I want to handle the auto suggestion text field in which typing few letters will automatically list the options from which i want to click and select the option. but I'm facing the issue in selecting the option from the list

Any Any Way of handling this ... please help with some suggestion im stuck on this .....
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrA00.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow !!!  Isn't it easier to google & try out something on your own before creating an account on SO just to ask a question without any research?

Answer (score 0):

```
After entering few characters wait until the screen which appears with suggestion using any xpath.


//Assume suggestionlist is your id 

driver.findelementbyid("suggestionlist")

One done take all elements in list.
@findby (id="suggestionlist")
List <AndroidElement> list;

once you get the list please manipulate that . 

foreach(element in list)
{
  if(element.gettext().equals("your desired value"))
  element.click();
}
```

Comment: My List contain names of cities which can vary time to time or when i write the character in text box..

Comment: you can directly click on first element list.get(0).click();